# Expectation and Variance

Tags: probability, expectation

For a random variable X, suppose that $E[X]=4$ and $Var(X)=9$. Then

(a.) $E[(3+X)^2]= ?$

(b.) $Var(2+4X)= ?$

I know the answer for (b.) is $4^2Var(X)=16*9=144$

But I do not know how to do (a.) especially with the square throwing me off.
I know that if it was only $E(3+x)$, I would just use the formula for it to be $3+E(X)$. But because there is a square, I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Expand the brackets within the expectation..and remember that the expectation is a linear operator. Do the terms look familiar at all?

Comment: To expand on what @Chinny84 said: $(X+3)^2 = ?$ and remember you can split up $\mathbb{E}$ additively.

Comment: @clarinetist you expanded and made it sound better ;)!

Comment: @Chinny84 Ok I got E(9)+E(6x)+E(x^2). How would I solve E(x^2)?

Comment: @a.m check my comment on the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Using the equation $$\sigma^2 = E[X^2]- \left( E[X] \right)^2,$$ we get $E[X^2]=25.$ For part (a), we expand to get $$E[(3+X)^2]=E[9]+6E[X]+E[X^2]=58.$$